# ¿Cómo manejar el evento de cerrar ventana en tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Tengo una ventana principal y necesito que al oprimir el botón <kbd>X</kbd> de cerrar ventana, se pida una confirmación de si desea realmente cerrar la aplicación o hacer otra cosa.

¿Cómo puedo capturar este evento para realizar una determinada acción cuando ocurra?

Comment: @FJSevilla  Gracias por el aporte, ya termine de implementarlo muchas gracias.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes interactuar entre la aplicación y el gestor de ventanas con el mecanismo conocido como *"[protocol handlers](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm#protocols)"*. Aunque esto puede variar, el protocolo general para cuando se pulsa el botón de cierre es `WM_DELETE_WINDOW`.

Si solo quieres pedir una confirmación de si se quiere salir de verdad, puedes usar `messagebox`:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

class MyApp:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_closing)

    def on_closing(self):
        d = MyDialog(root)
        self.parent.wait_window(d.top)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = MyApp(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

También puedes crear un "dialogo" más elaborado usando `toplevel`. En el siguiente ejemplo simplemente se pide si se quiere salir o solo minimizar:

```
import tkinter as tk


class MyDialog:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.top = tk.Toplevel(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.top.title("Salir")

        tk.Label(self.top, text="¿Está seguro?").grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)

        self.button1 = tk.Button(self.top, text="Si, salir de la app.", command=self.salir)
        self.button2 = tk.Button(self.top, text="No, solo minimizar.", command=self.minimizar)
        self.button1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.button2.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

    def salir(self):
        self.top.destroy()
        self.parent.destroy()

    def minimizar(self):
        self.top.destroy()
        self.parent.iconify()


class MyApp:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_closing)

    def on_closing(self):
        d = MyDialog(root)
        self.parent.wait_window(d.top)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = MyApp(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

**Ejemplo ejecución:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]